# Why do I get Subscript out of range error for array

Tags: arrays, vba

'''
Doing a simple sort function
'''

What am I doing wrong to receive 'Subscript out of range error" for the following code.

```
Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Arr = Range("B1:B4").Value
    
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(Arr)
          If Arr(i) > Arr(j) Then
            Temp = Arr(j)
            Arr(j) = Arr(i)
            Arr(i) = Temp
           End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: When I is at the upper bound j will be 1 greater than the upper bound. I should be until uboumd minus 1.

Comment: When I is at the upperbound the 'for J' loop will not run because j will be greater then ubound(arr)

Answer (score 0):

`Arr = Range("B1:B4").Value` creates a `4 Row X 1 Column` two dimensional array.  As such, you'll need to specify the second dimension...

```
Dim Temp As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range("B1:B4").Value

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(Arr)
      If Arr(i, 1) > Arr(j, 1) Then
        Temp = Arr(j, 1)
        Arr(j, 1) = Arr(i, 1)
        Arr(i, 1) = Temp
       End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Use 'Arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("B1:B4").Value)' to avoid getting a 2 dimensional array for a 1 dimensional range.

Comment: Thank You so much,everyone.